# Game Center Scores Stuck at a Particular Score

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center, leaderboard

I've been developing an app that posts scores to GC leaderboards and pulls them back down. Still in the dev phase, it does this to the sandbox envirenment. Recently I've noticed that the score increases like normal, I get the high score programatically and its correct, I can check the leaderboard, in-app, and its correct, and switch to the Game Center and it's correct. However, once I quit the app or stop posting scores for awhile, the scores disappear, reverting back to a particular score in the past or disappearing complete if the account is new.

Is this a known issue with GC or the sandbox? Some well known thing I'm not doing right? I'm really kinda puzzled at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you should not expect GC Sandbox to save your scores between sessions.

Just as you wouldn't expect a sandcastle to remain standing between trips to the sandbox in your kids playpark!